# Lubridate Converting Long Date Format to Short with Hours and Minutes

Tags: r, etl, data-manipulation, lubridate

I am attempting to convert the following column called `Date_Time`:

```
Wednesday, April 5, 2023 12:41:44 PM IST +01:00
```

INTO

```
2023-03-10 00:00:00.000
```

Using the code:

```
 fresh_data$Date_Time = as.Date(mdy_hms(fresh_data$Date.Processed))
```

But it is returning only:

```
2023-04-05
```

This is a slight issue as this is blocking an auto ingestion into an SQL DB, if someone could help i would appreciate it massively.

Comment: The `as.Date` function returns only the date component of your datetimes. Try using only `mdy_hms`, and include a time zone (`tz = ...`) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`?

```r
library(lubridate)

dt <- 'Wednesday, April 5, 2023 12:41:44 PM IST +01:00'

mdy_hms(dt) |>
  floor_date(unit = 'day') |>
  format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#> [1] "2023-04-05 00:00:00"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>